# From java class file to exe file

Tags: java, exe, launcher

I have just created an exe from a java class file using [Java Launcher](http://www.syncedit.com/software/javalauncher/).

After double clicking on the exe file it is not executing neither gives any response.
What mistake i have done here?

Comment: Try running it from the command line to see whether there is an error message.

Comment: My guess is that you've got classpath issues (did you bundle all the required jars within the main jar you turned into an exe?).  As the others have said, running from the command line will tell you these things.

Comment: First try to create a JAR file from that java class and try to run it using the cmd line : "java -jar YOUR_JAR_NAME.jar" without quotes.

If it doesn't work then you've got classpath/manifest issues.
Also make sure that any required library/jar is included within your project.

Answer (score 2):

First make a jar file and check it by running from cmd.
See the **MANIFEST.MF** in side jar. It should have main class like this.

```
Main-Class: com.mypackage.MyMainClass
```

Answer (score 2):

**It is possible that you would  have given the name of the main class wrong while making an exe file.**
Another way of creating exe file from .class file is :

First create jar file of .class files.To do this open cmd, go to the directory where you have .class files of that particular program.Then write jar  cvf  myjar.jar  *.class

A jar file is created in that directory.Then to make an exe file from that jar file you can use [jar to exe](http://www.brothersoft.com/jartoexe-75019.html) . When you create exe file using this software it will ask you to give the name of the main class of your program. Enter the main class there and your exe file is created.So as you click that exe file,your program runs.

**for directly converting .class file to exe file follow [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/159712).**

Answer (score 1):

try running your program from the command line to see if there are any errors.  One thing you could do is create a jar which is executable in windows which should work.

Comment: while runing through cmd it gives me as " 

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
myjar.jar"

Comment: You need to set it if you are doing it manually.  This is a pretty good reference on how to do this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html